# Is letting someone know you'll provide details "to follow" correct?

Tags: american-english, descriptive-grammar

I was told it is incorrect to send a meeting invite and note "agenda to follow"
I cannot find any grammatically info on whether this is incorrect. Is it because I have to say "Agenda to follow shortly"? Thank you!

Comment: It seems to me that it was deemed incorrect not on account of grammar but on account of vagueness. There are two possible ways to parse `agenda to follow`. This is not the csae with `Agenda to follow shortly`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with this; however, it is better to give a sense of the timing of when the agenda might follow.  However, in practice, used as you provided, I see "xxx to follow" commonly.